# Elasticsearch unable retrieve child documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently migrated Elasticsearch version 2.4 to 6.2.1 and my previous GET query is not working. Below is the query I am trying to retrieve the child document based on _id and _parent values. DO i have to change the implementation to retreive the documnets from ES?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": {
              "value": "9:v0",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "_parent": {
              "value": "v0",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "assoc.domainId": [
              "XX"
            ],
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "assoc.nodeId": [
              "YY"
            ],
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": false,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

parent document in ES:

```
{
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "assocjoin",
        "_id" : "v0",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "my_join_field" : {
            "name" : "version"
          },
          "versionnumber" : "v0",
          "versiondate" : "2018/03/29 13:25:02"
        }
      }
```

Child document in ES:

```
{
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "versionjoin",
        "_id" : "9:v0",
        "_score" : 0.18232156,
        "_routing" : "v0",
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 0,
          "assocDTO" : {
            "id" : 9,
            "domainId" : "XX",
            "nodeId" : "YY"
            },
            "biomarkers" : [
              {
               ....
              }
            ],
            "contexts" : [
              {
               ....
              }
            ]
          },
          "my_join_field" : {
            "name" : "assocversion",
            "parent" : "v0"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: @Val can you sugges me on this? Elasticsearch version 6.2.1

Comment: i do not see the _parent part in the query

Comment: I have modified the query to search by _parent.